# correct idiomatic byte buffer reading and writing

Tags: go

I have a net/socket open. I need to read a structured protocol off the wire. Ie I have

```
messagelength|type|value|type|value ...
```

where messagelength is 4 bytes, type one byte, value depends on type,...

I am trying to work out the no-brainer way of doing this in go. I am swamped by io,bufio,encoding... I cant find the right place to start and cant find samples. Looking for ReadInt32, ReadByte,....

Next thing - i need to assemble a reply -> WriteInt32, WriteString, WriteByte,....

Trying to convert python to go, python code uses struct.unpack / pack

Comment: Have a look at [encoding/binary](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/) and the functions it provides.

Comment: i did and was none the wiser, whats a varint, how do i connect a reader up to a net connection,...

Comment: varint is unimportant. You only need the Read() and Write() functions. Have a look at the examples, too.

Comment: [bytes.NewBuffer](http://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#NewBuffer) will return a `Buffer` you can use as an `io.Reader`

Comment: Tip: if both ends are written in Go - use [gobs](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/) for binary transfer. (This doesn't apply if the other end isn't a Go program).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the package [encoding/binary](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary). The only functions you will need are [Read()](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#Read) and [Write()](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#Write). Here is how you use them:

The Read() function has the following signature:

```
func Read(r io.Reader, order ByteOrder, data interface{}) error
```

This function reads from `r` in order `ByteOrder` into data. `data` must be a pointer to a fixed-size value (e.g. an `int32`, a byte or a struct with only fixed size members) or a slice of such values. If you pass a pointer to a struct, struct fields are read in without padding, data corresponding for blank fields (i.e. those named _) is read and discarded (ideal for padding).

For your specific problem, declare a struct that matches the header of your data stream.

```
type Header struct {
    Length uint32
    Type   uint8
}
```

Consume the header of a packet (assume big endian):

```
var hdr Header
if err = Read(connection, binary.BigEndian, &hdr); err != nil {
    // deal with read error
}
```

Switch over the type byte:

```
switch hdr.Type {
// for each type, read into a type-specific struct
// ...
}
```

`Write()` is similar but writes instead of reading.

Comment: how do I connect a net.Conn to an io.Reader

Comment: @pm100 a net.Conn is already an io.Reader: It's methods are a superset of the methods in io.Reader.

Comment: one more - how can i make an io.Reader from a []byte array